# Curve fitting exponential function with semilog x-axis

Tags: matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm having trouble fitting some date onto an exponential function with a semilog x-axis.

Following is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

kd=np.array[0.735420099, 0.700823723, 0.647775947,0.613179572,0.573970346,0.54398682,0.454036244,0.371004942,0.292586491,0.271828666,0.21878089,0.165733114,0.157660626,0.151894563]
ADAR = np.array[0.001012268,0.002028379,0.004015198,0.005931555,0.007948127,0.010143277,0.019594977,0.039746044,0.076782168,0.101639121,0.193968714,0.574178304,0.778822803,0.9878803]

def func(x,a,c,d):
    return a*np.exp(-c*x)+d
init_v = (1,1e-6,0)

opt,pcov = curve_fit(func,ADAR,kd,init_v)
a,c,d = opt

x2 = np.linspace(0.001,1)
y2 = func(x2,a,c,d)

plt.grid(True, which = "both")
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.scatter(ADAR,kd, c = 'blue')
ax.set_xscale('log')
plt.xlim([0.001,1])
plt.ylim([0,0.8])

plt.plot(x2,y2, '-', label = 'fit')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Area pressure coefficient')

plt.xlabel('AD/AR')
plt.ylabel('kd')

plt.show
```

Trying to fit the scatter plot:

[image: scatter plot fit]

Using Scipy Curve_fit with initial guesses I am unable to get a close fit of the data. Am I using the wrong function for this?

Comment: @JJacquelin that seems to have been rectified

Comment: You need to modify your model. With a combined root-product I get an exact fit. I'll post once the question allows me to.

Comment: In brief: `a * np.exp(b*x + c*np.sqrt(x)) + d` with parameters `[ 0.72854001,  1.81939298, -6.15652882,  0.1448764 ]`